# Is there any way to trace a python program like how pdb does but without actually executing it

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I just wanted to know if there is sometool or way to trace a python program similar to how pdb does but in offline mode as in without actually executing the code

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: You mean something like a brain that thinks about what would happen if you did execute the code?

Comment: But seriously, you can't trace a program unless you run it. If you need something to visualize what's going on, try http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Comment: Thanks @TimPietzcker .. the visual think is what I was expecting probably the question was not articulated well. :)